# Polarizer used in Michelson-Morley experiment

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, interferometry

Was in Michelson-Morley experiment a polarizer set in the half-silvered mirror that formed pi/4 radians respect to the other two mirrors?
I foumd no reference but I guess that in order to carry out the experiment, light should be linearly polarized.

Comment: Why does the light need to be linearly polarized?